# ID is undefined but it isn't?

Tags: javascript, attributes, set, undefined

Please look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DHts6/1/

Why does it say undefined, even though the `id = "foo"` is set!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `$(this).id`, just do `this.id`.

Reason for this is that `$` creates a jQuery object that doesn't have `.id` property. In jQuery you would use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) `$(this).attr('id')`

http://jsfiddle.net/DHts6/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.id` **not** `$(this).id`:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DHts6/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('b.edit').click(function(){
        $(this).hide().after('<form action = "foo.php" method = post><input name = "field" type = "text" value = "'+$(this).attr('id')+'"/><input type="text" name = "period" class="editP" value="'+$(this).html()+'" /><input type = "submit" value = "Submit!!" /></form>');
        $('.editP').focus();
    });
    $('.editP').live('blur', function(){
        $(this).hide().prev('b.edit').html($(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```